# ColdFusion 8: Disabling editing inside Rich Text Editor

Tags: rtf, coldfusion-8, disabled-input

Is there a way to make a rich text editor in ColdFusion read only? The disabled attribute does not appear to be working...

Answer (score 0):

As ColdFusion text editor is based on FCKEditor tool, include this javascript in your page and this will disable the editing and hide the controls. 
It's up to your need, you can only disable editing too.

```
    function FCKeditor_OnComplete( editorInstance )
{
// Just hiding the toolbar:
editorInstance.EditorWindow.parent.document.getElementById("xExpanded").style.display = "none";
// And hiding the small bar showing when the toolbar is collapsed is this:
editorInstance.EditorWindow.parent.document.getElementById("xCollapsed").style.display = "none";

// when you want to hide the collapse handle do:
editorInstance.EditorWindow.parent.document.getElementById("xCollapseHandle").style.display = "none";
// or hiding the expand handle. This seems to be the same as hiding the object with id 'xCollapsed' mentioned above:
editorInstance.EditorWindow.parent.document.getElementById("xExpandHandle").style.display = "none";

editorInstance.EditorDocument.body.contentEditable='false';
editorInstance.EditorDocument.designMode='off';
}
```

You can find the  [link here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=69) for more ways to do that.